# Angular - Directive is rendered first before variable evaluates?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive for showing all photos with a specific category:

```
<div ng-controller="CategoryController as c">
  <photo-set category="{{ c.category_name }}"></photo-set>
</div>
```

Strangely, the template is rendered first before the variable sets in. So, it thought the attribute is empty. If I hard-code the attribute like `<photo-set category="animal">` then it works fine.

There's no typo in the code, because when I inspect element, I can see the variable printed there.

```
 .directive("photoSet", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      templateUrl: "views/photo-set.html",
      scope: {
        category: "@category"
      },
      controller: "SetController", // the controller to render the photos
      controllerAs: "s"
    };
  })
```

My Category Controller:

```
.controller("CategoryController", function($routeParams) {
  this.category_name = $routeParams.category;
})

// the route is /c/:category
```

Edit: [The JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrsetyono/fcs3uraL/23/). In the fiddle, It can't work using `scope: { category: "@category" }`, so I replace it with `scope: true`

Comment: I think you don't need the double curly braces in the category property

Answer (score 0):

it is very much dependent on your template code. Like, there is no 'link' or 'compile' function, so it is not clear how you are using the category_name inside your template. Try passing it as object using '=' instead '@' expression and use it through scope only. And for faster help try posting sample fiddle

EDIT:

Like i said above, your 'directive template code' should use the variables set in directive scope(in your case your directive tag is different and `<ul>` tag is different this `<ul>` tag should be part of your directive template):

```
  <photo-set category="c.category_name">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="photo in s.photos">{{ photo.src }}</li>
    </ul>
  </photo-set>
```

should be

```
  <photo-set category="{{category_name}}"></photo-set>
```

and `<ul>` should be part of template

please checkout the working updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lp404d99/5/

more details about the execution flow 
http://jasonmore.net/angular-js-directives-difference-controller-link/

Comment: If something is not clear and you want to make request for code along with a suggestions, please use comments instead of answer. (... and until you can comment, do something else like editing posts, asking good questions or posting *real* answers)

Comment: Hi, I just added the JS Fiddle, could you help me take a look at it? Thanks